# Sonata Admin render "with" of Child

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I added a field contact (type: sonata_type_admin) to my `AdminClass` for Entity Activity.

My `ContactAdmin` looks like that:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper

        ->with('Adresse', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))
            ->add(
                'location.address',
                AddressType::class,
                array(
                    'label' => 'Adresse'
                ))
        ->end()

        ->with('Contact', array('label' => 'Contact'))
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'text')
            ->add('websiteUrl')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('telephoneNumber')
            ->add('telefaxNumber')
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

in my `ActivityAdmin` I added that:

```
$formMapper->add('contact', 'sonata_type_admin', array('label' => false));
```

Now I want that the fields form my `ContactAdmin` looks in my `ActivityAdmin` like they do if I directly open the `ContactAdmin`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you wanted.
You should look at the type form of sonata and especially sonata_type_collection

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection